# How to use document.getElementById with jquery next siblings selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to remove some silblings. I tried as given below.
But not working. why? And how to solve it?

```
<div>
  <div id="idx1">child1 </div>
  <div id="idx2">child2</div>
  <div id="idx3">child3</div>
  ...
  <div id="/a/b/c">This should be last child</div>
  <div id="idx4">Remove it.</div>
  <div id="idx5">Remove it.</div>
  <div id="idx6">Remove it.</div>
  ...
</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

 // Since the id contains special chars,
 // javascript method has been used to get the element.
 lastChildObj = jQuery(document.getElementById('a/b/c')); 

 // I don't know how to remove the childs after lastChildObj.
 // I tried as given below.
 lastChildObj.filter('~').remove();
```

Comment: This `/a/b/c` will always be at the fourth position ?

Comment: ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".") (HTML4 specification)

Comment: @MariusBalaban: Maybe he's using HTML5 ;-)

Comment: You know that you can use `jQuery` with this syntax : `$("#\\/a\\/b\\/c")` in order to retrieve your element!

Comment: @Cerbrus Browsers know all the web-developers are not expert in HTML4-specifications. So Browsers won't complain if we are using such ids :)

Comment: @Cerbrus I wanted to suggest that using "strange" characters may cause conflicts, but Samuel Caillerie did it better

Comment: @SamuelCaillerie How to escape it?

Comment: @habeebperwad, I know the ID won't be a problem, misdirected @, possibly? :P

Comment: @habeebperwad you use double backslash (`\\ `) before your special character (here : `/ `) in order to be understand by jQuery...

Comment: Any way thats one strange looking id that i ever seen ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two key steps to this.

1. Select the elements to remove
2. Remove them

Step 1 can be broken down into two parts, obtaining a reference to the last element to keep, then getting a list of all of its siblings that come after it. Step 2 just uses the `.remove()` function.

```
$(document.getElementById('/a/b/c')).nextAll().remove();
```

Comment: you should change your selector ^^

Comment: @EricG You should be more expressive. If you think there's an issue with my post, I'd appreciate it if you used your words and explained what that is, rather than posting cryptic comments.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: `$("#/a/b/c")`

Comment: Apologies, I thought it was obvious. Cerbrus helped you out ;) `$( element )` isnt valid. If the author posted an invalid selector, that's another part of the solution I guess.

Comment: @Cerbrus That's an invalid selector and will throw a syntax error: http://jsfiddle.net/szgSc/

Comment: Oh, the `/` have to be escaped it seems.

Comment: @EricG That's completely incorrect; passing a DOM element to the jQuery function to create a jQuery object containing just that element **is perfectly valid**. Have you ever seen jQuery code that does `$(this)`? Exactly the same thing. Read [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#using-dom-elements).

Comment: That's ok to have special characters in ids or classes, you just need to backslash the special characters as jQuery doc says : http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: @jerome.s Yes, it's valid *if you escape them*, but it's not if you don't. Though I personally think using `document.getElementById()` to select the actual DOM element is easier than escaping special characters in the selector for jQuery.

Comment: @Anthony You are right, my bad. I didn't realize this and it was a short'minded' remark (too fast without thinking). I expected the selector right away :p

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
var base = document.getElementById('/a/b/c');
while(base.nextSibling){ // While the element has siblings
    base.parentElement.removeChild(base.nextSibling); // remove the siblings from the parent element.
}
```

**[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/nny6G/)**

You can also make it slightly more efficient:

```
var base = document.getElementById('/a/b/c');
while(base.parentElement.removeChild(base.nextSibling))​ // Remove the nextSiblings while they exist.
```

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/QDjWG/)**

Comment: Would the person that downvoted me please explain why? If I made a mistake, I'd like to learn from it.

Comment: if I am not mistaken you can just ";" instead "{}". ohh and this is not related to vote it is just a side note to your answer.

Comment: Good method since it is using pure JavaScript. But I prefer to use jQuery method suggested by @Anthony Grist.

Comment: @habeebperwad: may I ask why you prefer to use the JQ method?

Comment: @Cerbrus JQuery code is simple and easy to understand. That will work in most of the browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use jquery for your selector but you need to escape the id like so :

```
$("#\\/a\\/b\\/c")
```

Then you just need to select any following divs like this :

```
$("#\\/a\\/b\\/c").nextAll().remove();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8mMJq/

Further informations about special characters in selectors : http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Which function can use to escape?

Comment: You don't use any function you just double backslash it like I did, look at the fiddle is working. More informations here : http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: The id name is getting dynamically. So I need a escape function such as escape(). Which function should use to escape the id name?

Comment: You will probably need to write your own then. There's no function allowing you to do that in jQuery as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$("#\\/a\\/b\\/c").nextAll().remove();
```

JsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/QcvWQ/

Answer (score -2):

First of all change id from "/a/b/c" to ie "abc" and then run following

```
$("#abc").nextAll().each(function () { $(this).remove());});
```

Comment: If I have two ids "/a/b/c" and "/a/bc", what will happen?

Comment: Please clarify why anyone shoud use specific characters like '/' in html tag id? why was my answer evaluated to -2? I do not understand. It is working code...

Comment: In HTML5 its allowed to have an id like `/a/b/c` as @Cerbrus suggests (Im still unsure in that)

Comment: @MarcinBuciora It is your first day in StackOverflow. That is why you don't understand it :) After one or two month you can understand such things.

Comment: Yes, you can use it in html5 [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/sebastienp/DvEnQ/) but for what reason you would do that?